# How can I dynamically change html.Button text in dash?

Tags: html, button, text, dynamic, plotly-dash

I have tried different attributes ( title, data, value, etc ) but they dont do the trick.  Below is the sample code taken directly from the dash documentation.  I simply would like to be able to push the button and have the button text change to something else besides "Submit", preferably the input text.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(dcc.Input(id='input-on-submit', type='text')),
    html.Button('Submit', id='submit-val', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='container-button-basic',
             children='Enter a value and press submit')
])


@app.callback(
    Output('container-button-basic', 'children'),
    Input('submit-val', 'n_clicks'),
    dash.dependencies.State('input-on-submit', 'value')
)

def update_output(n_clicks, value):
    
    return ('The input value was "{}" and the button has been clicked {} times'.format(
        value,
        n_clicks
    ))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found that I needed to update the "children" property.  Below is code that performs the function I was looking for:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(dcc.Input(id='input-on-submit', type='text')),
    html.Button('Submit', id='submit-val', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='container-button-basic',
             children='Enter a value and press submit')
])


@app.callback(
    Output('container-button-basic', 'children'),
    Output ('submit-val','children'),
    Input('submit-val', 'n_clicks'),
    dash.dependencies.State('input-on-submit', 'value')
)

def update_output(n_clicks, value):
    
    if n_clicks==0:
        return
    else:
        buttonText = value
    
    
    return ('The input value was "{}" and the button has been clicked {} times'.format(
        value,
        n_clicks
    ), buttonText)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).